# Why does this function continues to run?

Tags: java, function, recursion, return, return-value

I have this exercise and I need to write a java funtion to find out if zero can be reached using only addition and subtraction for a given series of numbers. As an example let us consider these numbers 5,3,2,4,1,0,3 I can use addition and subtraction to reach zero 5+3-2-4+1+0-3=0. Another example will be  7+3-8+5-3-4-0 = 0 and the function should work recursively. A solution is given but I really don't understand how it works.

```
public static boolean addCalcExists(int[] values, int position, int result) {
    if (position < values.length) {
        boolean p = addCalcExists(values, position + 1, result + values[position]);
        boolean n = addCalcExists(values, position + 1, result - values[position]);
        return p || n;
    }

    return result == 0;
}
```

I have debugged the code in eclipse and run it step by step first for the boolean value p the series add up to 18 for these numbers (5,3,2,4,1,0,3)  then this return statement is evaluated

```
return result == 0;
```

This returns obviously false then the program goes p value again assigns it the value false then the n value is evaluated which is also false then program evaluates this statement

```
return p || n;
```

which also returns false but then it goes back to p value again and this time the position value is decremented by one. Why does it do that shouldn't it retun false and end the execution?

Comment: When `return result == 0` is executed, that only terminates the current call at the top of the call stack. Then the next call below it in the call stack - i.e. whichever one made the previous recursive call and waited for its result - resumes with the result that was returned. That is how recursive functions are executed. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack

Comment: Yeah it just sounds like you are moving back through the recursive call stack.